# How to select a word with special characters in LIvecode

Tags: livecode

How to select a word with with special characters (eg: usa-uk). the following code will select text but it's doesn't select the words like usa-uk. How I change my code

```
select the mouseText
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a huge text in your field you might use:

```
on mouseMove
   if the mouseLoc is within the rect of me then
      put the mouseChunk into tChunk
      # Check if chars before or after is a "spacing char"
      put word 2 of tChunk into tstart
      put word 4 of tChunk into tEnd
      repeat with i = tStart down to 1 step -1
         if matchText(char i of me, "\s") then exit repeat
      end repeat
      put i+1 into tStart
      repeat with i = tEnd to the number of chars of me
         if matchText(char i of me, "\s") then exit repeat
      end repeat
      put i-1 into tEnd
      select char tstart to tEnd of me
   end if
end mouseMove
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting? For example, if this was in the field script:

`on mousemove
   select the mouseText
end mouse move`

You would be selecting the text under the cursor. In order to select compound text such as "usa-uk" you would have to group that text fragment. This sets the textStyle of that fragment to "link".

Craig Newman